# Dimension of vector space of real-valued functions over $R$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the space of real-valued functions on the closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a < b$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

---

$V$: The space of real-valued functions on the closed interval.

$W$: Subset of $V$ where all the coefficients are set to 1.

If I consider the polynomials $1,x,x^2,~...~x^n$ (Where all these polynomials are linearly independent), I can repeatedly create a polynomial $x^{n+1}$ which is linearly independent, and thus the basis is of infinite order for $W$, $W$ is infinite dimensional and this implies that $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Am I getting anywhere? Would appreciate feedback.

Comment: Sure, this will work.  You didn't restrict your attention to continuous functions, so you could also work with functions of the form $$f_c(x)=\begin{cases}1&x=c\\0&x\not=c\end{cases}.$$  It's easier to show that those are independent.

Comment: Oh, I interpreted the exercise as "continous, polynomials".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are getting somewhere. But you are not expressing yourself in the best possible way. First of all what are the coefficients of a function? In the second place, you should define $W$ as the space of the polynomal functions from $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$. Yes, $W\subset V$ and, yes, $W$ is infinite-dimensional (from which you can deduce that $V$ itself is infinite-dimensional). The reason for this is that, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $x^n\notin\langle1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks! The coefficients of the polynomials of $W$ are vectors, where $a_i$ is the coefficient of the term of degree $i$. The way I defined $W$ would imply that all coefficients were set to 1, is that what you mean?

Comment: @SimonIversen No, I don't mean that. You define $W$ as the set of those functions “where all the coefficients are set to $1$”. What *are* the coefficients of a function? For instance, what are the coefficients of the functions $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$?

Comment: Yup! There I got it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @SimonIversen You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This does not make sense to talk about a basis for $W$ since $W$ is not a subspace (not stable by sum). You don't need to introduce anything new, simply to show that $x^{n+1}$ is not in the span of $\{1,x, \dots, x^n\}$, this will shows that a basis of $V$ can't be finite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what it means that $W$ is not stable by sum?

Comment: You defined $W$ to be the polynomials with coefficient $1$ (if I understood correctly) but $x + x = 2x \notin W$ so $W$ is not a linear subspace of $V$.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonIversen : you are welcome !